# Maven versioning issue, mvn3 looks into maven2 repo

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am explicetely run maven 3 to build my project:

```
sudo /usr/share/maven3/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn clean install
```

I received error like this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.jboss.bom:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:1.0.4.Final-redhat-9 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository
...
```

I don't want to delete my `maven2` it exist separately.

**Question**: What have I forgotten to get done to get maven3 work w/o errors?

Comment: The artifact does not exist in Maven Central. Why do you need a `sudo ...` to run Maven ?

Comment: I don't need sudo, I got same errors, w/o sudo. Isn't it strange that mvn3 looks into central for maven 2? Edited: Answered by A. Di Matteo below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no conflict between Maven 3 and Maven 2, `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` is default repository in Maven 3, even though its name and suffix may be misleading, mentioning the ending `2`, but most probably kept for backward compatibility.

The default repository for Maven 3 is per [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html):

> ```
> <repositories>
>     <repository>
>       <id>central</id>
>       <name>Central Repository</name>
>       <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
>       <layout>default</layout>
>       <snapshots>
>         <enabled>false</enabled>
>       </snapshots>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
> ```

The same applies to the local cache, `.m2` folder, again, it is the [default](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for Maven 3 as well.

> ```
> <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
> ```

Your issue hence is not related to conflict between Maven versions, but due to wrong coordinates of the concerned dependency.

The [existing related one](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.bom/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools/1.0.4.Final) is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But you specified an additional `classifier`: `redhat-9`, which is not available in Maven central repository, hence the error.